# Updating website made from HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: html, css, web-hosting

I've a question in mind where if I want to add new post to blog-website I code from scratch with html5 and css3. Do I have to upload new index.html every-time to web hosting? or it can be done by any other way. Just wondering.

Comment: It would be better if you add new post of your blog website in the existing files and upload it to the server

Comment: just wondering if a feature like create a new post eg; (blogger,wordpress) which make posting easier available if i build a website from scratch?

Comment: Other way is to create a new blog file and link it,....wordpress automatically adds the blog update

Answer (score 0):

if you use PHP or ASP (or other server language) dont need upload file. just need design template and save your post data in database. and for show page need fetch database and create page dynamically.

work with CMS is very simple. I'm recommend to you, use Cms similar wordpress